# module jdk.translet does not read unnamed module

Tags: java, apache-fop, java-module

I do get the error in my PowerMock test and I found out that it runs fine outside of the test:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class 
die.verwandlung.GregorSamsa (in module jdk.translet) cannot access class 
com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.runtime.AbstractTranslet (in unnamed module 
@0x12c60152) because module jdk.translet does not read unnamed module @0x12c60152
```

I tried to `--add-reads jdk.translet=ALL-UNNAMED`but the module is not know to java.

Does anybody have a solution for this?

Comment: Is `jdk.translet` your module? If so, I'd strongly suggest you name it something that doesn't start with `jdk.` as that prefix is used for modules that ship with the JDK. I don't know if that is actively causing problems, but at the very least it'll cause confusion.

Comment: I'm not creating any modules but it might be something a dependency creates. For example apache fop. I'm also a bit confused by `die.verwandlung.GregorSamsa`. A very weird classname.

`com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc` is in the java.xml module and contains a class with the name 'Translet'. I assume the module name comes from that.

Comment: So `die.verwandlung.GregorSamsa` is not your class? You need to provide a lot more info on what you're actually doing. What code are you trying to run? What does your command line look like?

Comment: I actually assume this is just a module thing and the error line gives enough explanation for experts on the module system. I will also ask the forum who created the apache fop package

Comment: Looks like that class name comes from Apache Xalan (which is used internally by the JDK for XSLT implementation): https://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/xsltc/xsltc_native_api.html What's weird is that the XSLT implementation is shipped with the JDK itself, so it should not run into these kinds of "have not thought of modules" problems ... Still, if you can't provide an [mre] then odds are that people won't be able to point to a specific solution.

Comment: I fully agree. Very weird

Comment: If nobody has a working suggestion I'll indeed have to create a demo but for now I hope that I can fix it without that :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257189/discussion-between-milo-van-der-zee-and-joachim-sauer).